# Url validation with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why in following code don't work this part `if(!$(this).val()){...` from code and this match is true with `http://www.st`, i want as: `http://stackoverflow.com` ?

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/gp9nL/3/

```
$('.url').keyup(function(){
    if (!$(this).val().match(/^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \?=.-]*)*\/?$/)){
        $(this).css("background", "#ffc4c4");
        result = false;
    }else {
        $(this).css("background", "#FFFFEC");
        result = true;
    }
    if(!$(this).val()){
        alert('field is empty')
        $(this).css("background", "#FFFFEC");
    }
    return result;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

`if(!$(this).val())`

is probably not working because it is being called on `keyup`

`$('.url').keyup(function(){`

Therefore, there will always be something in the `input`, as a key stroke is needed to fire keyup and it will never evaluate as empty.

**EDIT**

As per the comment

> What's the solution?

If you want to check if the field is empty, do the check on `focusout`.

Here is your updated code:

```
$('.url').focusout(function(){

    if(!$(this).val()){
        alert('field is empty')
        $(this).css("background", "#FFFFEC");
    }        
});
```

And your fiddle updated: http://jsfiddle.net/gp9nL/4/